# C++ Mutually Recursive Variant Type

Tags: c++, recursion, types, boost-variant, mutual-recursion

I am trying to represent a PDF object type in c++ using variants. A PDF object is one of the following:

- `Boolean`
- `Integer`
- `Real`
- `String`
- `Name`
- `Stream`
- `Array<Object>`
- `Map<Object, Object>`

As you can see, the `Object` type is mutually recursive because the `Array` type would require a declaration of the `Map` type which would require a declaration of the `Array` type. How could I go abouts representing this type in c++? If a variant isn't the best way, what is?

Here is what I have tried so far but it doesn't compile because of the requirements of `std::unordered_map` (I think) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/699082582e73376e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `boost::variant`, what is wrong about using its recursive wrappers ?

- [recursive_variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#header.boost.variant.recursive_variant_hpp)
- [recursive_wrapper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#header.boost.variant.recursive_wrapper_hpp)

You can see a short example in the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive.recursive-variant):

```
typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<
      int
    , std::vector< boost::recursive_variant_ >
    >::type int_tree_t;

std::vector< int_tree_t > subresult;
subresult.push_back(3);
subresult.push_back(5);

std::vector< int_tree_t > result;
result.push_back(1);
result.push_back(subresult);
result.push_back(7);

int_tree_t var(result);
```

And it works as expected.

Comment: The problem is that there is mutual recursion between the array and dictionary types. This example only shows how to nest an `int_tree_t` in a variant of itself, however I need to refer to a typedef which hasn't been defined yet

Comment: @Ell: I do not see such recursion. Both refer to `Object`, which is (I guess) the variant you are defining, but I would think that `typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<Boolean, Integer, ..., Array<boost::recursive_variant_>, Map<boost::recursive_variant_, boost::recursive_variant_>>::type Object;` would work just fine.

Comment: Ahh of course. I'm sorry, I didn't see how I could use that, but of course I just don't need the typedef. Thank you very much and my apologies for not seeing that this is the solution the first time!

Comment: @Ell: you don't have to be sorry about it :)

Comment: How to get data from this `int_tree_t` object? I expected something like `boost::get<int>(boost::get<std::vector<int_tree_t>>(var)[0])` to return 1, but it does not compile because `boost::get` is not defined for recursive variants.

Comment: @AntonK: I am surprised that `get` does not work. In this case I suppose that you will have to switch to the visitor-based approach.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It actually works, I have misunderstanded error message, it's quite long :) Here is an example: http://paste.org.ru/?jvz4ar