# How to overcome a Boost Spirit AST snafu

Tags: c++, boost, protocol-buffers, abstract-syntax-tree

For starters, I have an AST in which I have to do a [forward declaration](http://wandbox.org/permlink/NI2Luvrw1HF7lF1E), but apparently this is not exactly kosher in the latest C++ compilers?

Overcoming this I can work through the rest of the grammar, I believe. For reference, I am writing the parser more or less faithfully  to the [Google Protobuf v2 specification](http://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto2-spec).

If memory serves, this has something to do with perhaps introducing a type def? And/or Boost Spirit recursive descent, i.e. `recursive_wrapper`? But it's been a little while, I'm a bit fuzzy on those details. Would someone mind taking a look?

But for the forward declaration issue I think the posted code is mostly grammar complete. TBD are `Protobuf` *service*, *rpc*, *stream*, and, of course, comments.

There may be a couple of variant gremlins lurking in there as well I'm not sure what to do with; i.e. how to synthesize a *"nil"* or `empty_statement`, for instance, pops up a couple of times throughout the grammatical alternatives.

Comment: I [resolved a couple of obvious typos](http://wandbox.org/permlink/tM6vQilplqDOL4v5), so what remains are the forward declaration concerns, I think.

Comment: Now the [forward declaration errors](http://wandbox.org/permlink/WeRqkmDR93Wqu8BI) are top most.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think they are

Comment: Sorry, don't think what are? Updated [example code](http://wandbox.org/permlink/NZMYLnK2y2sJFR3H). If you are referring to the forward declaration errors, they are happening first. I'd paste it here, but not enough room. See example code.

Comment: I've been looking at it for a good few hours now. I'll post tips/hints when it compiles.

Comment: Yeah, I apologize for the really rough draft code. Bad on my part. Hopefully the latest code updates are now focused on the question at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does one end up with such a vast body of untested code? I suppose it makes sense to look at a minimized version of this code from scratch and stop at the earliest point it stops working, instead of postponing sanity checks until it's become unmanageable.¹

I'm going to point you at some places where you can see what to do.

- [Recursive using declaration with boost variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122683/recursive-using-declaration-with-boost-variant/48133927#48133927)
- [C++ Mutually Recursive Variant Type (Again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803729/c-mutually-recursive-variant-type-again/45805699#45805699)

I have to warn I don't think `std::variant` or `std::optional` are supported yet by Qi. I could be wrong.

---

### Review And Fixup Round

I spent entirely too much time trying to fix the many issues, subtle and not so subtle.

I'll be happy to explain a bit, but for now I'm just dropping the result:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/573d942b1a524b5d)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_auto.hpp>
//#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>

namespace AST {
    using boost::variant;
    using boost::optional;

    enum class bool_t { false_, true_ };
    enum class syntax_t { proto2 };

    using str_t = std::string;

    struct full_id_t {
        std::string full_id;
    };

    using int_t = intmax_t;
    using float_t = double;

    /// See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/calc8/ast.hpp
    /// Specifically, struct nil {}.
    struct empty_statement_t {};

    // TODO: TBD: we may need/want to dissect this one still further... i.e. to ident, message/enum-name, etc.
    struct element_type_t : std::string {
        using std::string::string;
        using std::string::operator=;
    };

    // TODO: TBD: let's not get too fancy with the inheritance, ...
    // TODO: TBD: however, scanning the other types, we could potentially do more of it, strategically, here and there
    struct msg_type_t : element_type_t {};
    struct enum_type_t : element_type_t {};

    struct package_t {
        std::string full_id;
    };

    using const_t = variant<full_id_t, int_t, float_t, str_t, bool_t>;

    struct import_modifier_t {
        std::string val;
    };

    struct import_t {
        optional<import_modifier_t> mod;
        std::string target_name;
    };

    struct option_t {
        std::string name;
        const_t val;
    };

    using label_t = std::string;

    using type_t = variant<std::string, msg_type_t, enum_type_t>;

    // TODO: TBD: could potentially get more meta-dissected based on the specification:
    struct field_opt_t {
        std::string name;
        const_t val;
    };

    struct field_t {
        label_t label; // this would benefit from being an enum instead
        type_t type;
        std::string name;
        int_t number;
        std::vector<field_opt_t> opts;
    };

    // TODO: TBD: add extend_t after msg_t ...
    struct field_t;
    struct enum_t;
    struct msg_t;
    struct extend_t;
    struct extensions_t;
    struct group_t;
    struct option_t;
    struct oneof_t;
    struct map_field_t;
    struct reserved_t;

    using msg_body_t = std::vector<variant<
        field_t,
        enum_t,
        msg_t,
        extend_t,
        extensions_t,
        group_t,
        option_t,
        oneof_t,
        map_field_t,
        reserved_t,
        empty_statement_t
    >>;

    struct group_t {
        label_t label;
        std::string name;
        int_t number;
        msg_body_t body;
    };

    struct oneof_field_t {
        type_t type;
        std::string name;
        int_t number;
        optional<std::vector<field_opt_t>> opts;
    };

    struct oneof_t {
        std::string name;
        std::vector<variant<oneof_field_t, empty_statement_t>> choices;
    };

    struct key_type_t {
        std::string val;
    };

    struct map_field_t {
        key_type_t key_type;
        type_t type;
        std::string name;
        int_t number;
        optional<std::vector<field_opt_t>> opts;
    };

    struct range_t {
        int_t min;
        optional<int_t> max;
    };

    struct extensions_t {
        std::vector<range_t> ranges;
    };

    struct reserved_t {
        variant<std::vector<range_t>, std::vector<std::string>> val;
    };

    struct enum_val_opt_t {
        std::string name;
        const_t val;
    };

    struct enum_field_t {
        std::string name;
        std::string ordinal;
        std::vector<enum_val_opt_t> opt; // consistency
    };

    using enum_body_t = std::vector<variant<option_t, enum_field_t, empty_statement_t> >;

    struct enum_t {
        std::string name;
        enum_body_t body;
    };

    struct msg_t {
        std::string name;
        // TODO: TBD: here is another case where forward declaration is necessary in terms of the AST definition.
        msg_body_t body;
    };

    struct extend_t {
        using content_t = variant<field_t, group_t, empty_statement_t>;

        // TODO: TBD: actually, this use case may beg the question whether
        // "message type", et al, in some way deserve a first class definition?
        msg_type_t msg_type;
        std::vector<content_t> content;
    };

    struct top_level_def_t {
        // TODO: TBD: may add svc_t after extend_t ...
        variant<msg_t, enum_t, extend_t> content;
    };

    struct proto_t {
        syntax_t syntax;
        std::vector<variant<import_t, package_t, option_t, top_level_def_t, empty_statement_t>> content;
    };

    template <typename T>
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const&) {
        std::operator<<(os, "[");
        std::operator<<(os, typeid(T).name());
        std::operator<<(os, "]");
        return os;
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::option_t, name, val)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::full_id_t, full_id)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::package_t, full_id)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::import_modifier_t, val)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::import_t, mod, target_name)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::field_opt_t, name, val)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::field_t, label, type, name, number, opts)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::group_t, label, name, number, body)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::oneof_field_t, type, name, number, opts)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::oneof_t, name, choices)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::key_type_t, val)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::map_field_t, key_type, type, name, number, opts)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::range_t, min, max)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::extensions_t, ranges)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::reserved_t, val)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::enum_val_opt_t, name, val)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::enum_field_t, name, ordinal, opt)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::enum_t, name, body)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::msg_t, name, body)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::extend_t, msg_type, content)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::top_level_def_t, content)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::proto_t, syntax, content)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template<typename It>
struct ProtoGrammar : qi::grammar<It, AST::proto_t()> {

    using char_rule_type   = qi::rule<It, char()>;
    using string_rule_type = qi::rule<It, std::string()>;
    using skipper_type     = qi::space_type;

    ProtoGrammar() : ProtoGrammar::base_type(start) {

        using qi::lit;
        using qi::digit;
        using qi::lexeme; // redundant, because no rule declares a skipper
        using qi::char_;

        // Identifiers
        id = lexeme[qi::alpha >> *char_("A-Za-z0-9_")];
        full_id      = id;
        msg_name     = id;
        enum_name    = id;
        field_name   = id;
        oneof_name   = id;
        map_name     = id;
        service_name = id;
        rpc_name     = id;
        stream_name  = id;

        // These distincions aren't very useful until in the semantic analysis
        // stage. I'd suggest to not conflate that with parsing.
        msg_type  = qi::as_string[ -char_('.') >> *(qi::hold[id >> char_('.')]) >> msg_name ];
        enum_type = qi::as_string[ -char_('.') >> *(qi::hold[id >> char_('.')]) >> enum_name ];

        // group_name = lexeme[qi::upper >> *char_("A-Za-z0-9_")];
        // simpler:
        group_name = &qi::upper >> id;

        // Integer literals
        oct_lit = &char_('0')       >> qi::uint_parser<AST::int_t, 8>{};
        hex_lit = qi::no_case["0x"] >> qi::uint_parser<AST::int_t, 16>{};
        dec_lit =                      qi::uint_parser<AST::int_t, 10>{};
        int_lit = lexeme[hex_lit | oct_lit | dec_lit]; // ordering is important

        // Floating-point literals
        float_lit = qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double> >{};

        // String literals
        oct_esc  = '\\' >> qi::uint_parser<unsigned char, 8, 3, 3>{};
        hex_esc  = qi::no_case["\\x"] >> qi::uint_parser<unsigned char, 16, 2, 2>{};
        // The last bit in this phrase is literally, "Or Any Characters Not in the Sequence" (fixed)
        char_val = hex_esc | oct_esc | char_esc | ~char_("\0\n\\");
        str_lit  = lexeme["'" >> *(char_val - "'") >> "'"]
            | lexeme['"' >> *(char_val - '"') >> '"']
            ;

        // Empty Statement - likely redundant
        empty_statement = ';' >> qi::attr(AST::empty_statement_t{});

        // Constant
        const_
            = bool_lit
            | str_lit
            | float_lit // again, ordering is important
            | int_lit
            | full_id
            ;

        // keyword helper
        #define KW(p) (lexeme[(p) >> !(qi::alnum | '_')])
        // Syntax
        syntax = KW("syntax") >> '=' >> lexeme[ lit("'proto2'") | "\"proto2\"" ] >> ';' >> qi::attr(AST::syntax_t::proto2);

        // Import Statement
        import_modifier = KW("weak") | KW("public");
        import = KW("import") >> -import_modifier >> str_lit >> ';';

        // Package
        package = KW("package") >> full_id >> ';';

        // Option
        opt_name = qi::raw[ (id | '(' >> full_id >> ')') >> *('.' >> id) ];

        opt = KW("option") >> opt_name >> '=' >> const_ >> ';';

        // Fields
        field_num = int_lit;
        label = KW("required")
            | KW("optional")
            | KW("repeated")
            ;

        type 
            = KW(builtin_type)
            | msg_type
            | enum_type
            ;

        // Normal field
        field_opt  = opt_name >> '=' >> const_;
        field_opts = -('[' >> field_opt % ',' >> ']');
        field      = label >> type >> field_name >> '=' >> field_num >> field_opts >> ';';

        // Group field
        group      = label >> KW("group") >> group_name >> '=' >> field_num >> msg_body;

        // Oneof and oneof field
        oneof_field = type >> field_name >> '=' >> field_num >> field_opts >> ';';
        oneof       = KW("oneof") >> oneof_name >> '{'
            >> *(
                    oneof_field
                    // TODO: TBD: ditto how to handle "empty" not synthesizing any attributes ...
                    | empty_statement
                ) >> '}';

        // Map field
        key_type = KW(builtin_type);

        // mapField = "map" "<" keyType "," type ">" mapName "=" fieldNumber [ "[" fieldOptions "]" ] ";"
        map_field = KW("map") >> '<' >> key_type >> ',' >> type >> '>' >> map_name
            >> '=' >> field_num >> field_opts >> ';';

        // Extensions and Reserved, Extensions ...
        range      = int_lit >> -(KW("to") >> (int_lit | KW("max")));
        ranges     = range % ',';
        extensions = KW("extensions") >> ranges >> ';';

        // Reserved
        reserved    = KW("reserved") >> (ranges | field_names) >> ';';
        field_names = field_name % ',';

        // Enum definition
        enum_val_opt  = opt_name >> '=' >> const_;
        enum_val_opts = -('[' >> (enum_val_opt % ',') >> ']');
        enum_field    = id >> '=' >> int_lit >> enum_val_opts >> ';';
        enum_body     = '{' >> *(opt | enum_field | empty_statement) >> '}';
        enum_         = KW("enum") >> enum_name >> enum_body;

        // Message definition
        msg = KW("message") >> msg_name >> msg_body;
        msg_body = '{' >> *(
                field
                | enum_
                | msg
                | extend
                | extensions
                | group
                | opt
                | oneof
                | map_field
                | reserved
                //// TODO: TBD: how to "include" an empty statement ... ? "empty" does not synthesize anything, right?
                | empty_statement
                ) >> '}';

        // Extend
        extend_content = field | group | empty_statement;
        extend_contents = '{' >> *extend_content >> '}';
        extend = KW("extend") >> msg_type >> extend_contents;

        top_level_def = msg | enum_ | extend /*| service*/;
        proto = syntax >> *(import | package | opt | top_level_def | empty_statement);
        start = qi::skip(qi::space) [ proto ];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
            (id) (full_id) (msg_name) (enum_name) (field_name) (oneof_name)
            (map_name) (service_name) (rpc_name) (stream_name) (group_name)
            (msg_type) (enum_type)
            (oct_lit) (hex_lit) (dec_lit) (int_lit)
            (float_lit)
            (oct_esc) (hex_esc) (char_val) (str_lit)
            (empty_statement)
            (const_)
            (syntax)
            (import_modifier) (import)
            (package)
            (opt_name) (opt)
            (field_num)
            (label)
            (type)
            (field_opt) (field_opts) (field)
            (group)
            (oneof_field)
            (oneof)
            (key_type) (map_field)
            (range) (ranges) (extensions) (reserved)
            (field_names)
            (enum_val_opt) (enum_val_opts) (enum_field) (enum_body) (enum_)
            (msg) (msg_body)
            (extend_content) (extend_contents) (extend)
            (top_level_def) (proto))
    }

  private:
    struct escapes_t : qi::symbols<char, char> {
        escapes_t() { this->add
                ("\\a",  '\a')
                ("\\b",  '\b')
                ("\\f",  '\f')
                ("\\n",  '\n')
                ("\\r",  '\r')
                ("\\t",  '\t')
                ("\\v",  '\v')
                ("\\\\", '\\')
                ("\\'",  '\'')
                ("\\\"", '"');
        }
    } char_esc;

    string_rule_type id, full_id, msg_name, enum_name, field_name, oneof_name,
                     map_name, service_name, rpc_name, stream_name, group_name;

    qi::rule<It, AST::msg_type_t(), skipper_type> msg_type;
    qi::rule<It, AST::enum_type_t(), skipper_type> enum_type;

    qi::rule<It, AST::int_t()> int_lit, dec_lit, oct_lit, hex_lit;
    qi::rule<It, AST::float_t()> float_lit;

    /// true | false
    struct bool_lit_t : qi::symbols<char, AST::bool_t> {
        bool_lit_t() { this->add
            ("true", AST::bool_t::true_)
            ("false", AST::bool_t::false_);
        }
    } bool_lit;

    char_rule_type oct_esc, hex_esc, char_val;
    qi::rule<It, AST::str_t()> str_lit;

    // TODO: TBD: there are moments when this is a case in a variant or vector<variant>
    qi::rule<It, AST::empty_statement_t(), skipper_type> empty_statement;

    qi::rule<It, AST::const_t(), skipper_type> const_;

    /// syntax = {'proto2' | "proto2"} ;
    qi::rule<It, AST::syntax_t(), skipper_type> syntax;

    /// import [weak|public] <targetName/> ;
    qi::rule<It, AST::import_t(), skipper_type> import;
    qi::rule<It, AST::import_modifier_t(), skipper_type> import_modifier;

    /// package <fullIdent/> ;
    qi::rule<It, AST::package_t(), skipper_type> package;

    /// option <optionName/> = <const/> ;
    qi::rule<It, AST::option_t(), skipper_type> opt;
    /// <ident/> | "(" <fullIdent/> ")" ("." <ident/>)*
    string_rule_type opt_name;

    qi::rule<It, AST::label_t(), skipper_type> label;
    qi::rule<It, AST::type_t(), skipper_type> type;

    struct builtin_type_t : qi::symbols<char, std::string> {
        builtin_type_t() { this->add
            ("double", "double")
            ("float", "float")
            ("int32", "int32")
            ("int64", "int64")
            ("uint32", "uint32")
            ("uint64", "uint64")
            ("sint32", "sint32")
            ("sint64", "sint64")
            ("fixed32", "fixed32")
            ("fixed64", "fixed64")
            ("sfixed32", "sfixed32")
            ("sfixed64", "sfixed64")
            ("bool", "bool")
            ("string", "string")
            ("bytes", "bytes");
        }
    } builtin_type;
    qi::rule<It, AST::int_t()> field_num;

    qi::rule<It, AST::field_opt_t(), skipper_type> field_opt;
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<AST::field_opt_t>(), skipper_type> field_opts;
    qi::rule<It, AST::field_t(), skipper_type> field;

    qi::rule<It, AST::group_t(), skipper_type> group;

    qi::rule<It, AST::oneof_t(), skipper_type> oneof;
    qi::rule<It, AST::oneof_field_t(), skipper_type> oneof_field;

    qi::rule<It, AST::key_type_t(), skipper_type> key_type;
    qi::rule<It, AST::map_field_t(), skipper_type> map_field;

    /// <int/> [ to ( <int/> | "max" ) ]
    qi::rule<It, AST::range_t(), skipper_type> range;
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<AST::range_t>(), skipper_type> ranges;
    /// extensions <ranges/> ;
    qi::rule<It, AST::extensions_t(), skipper_type> extensions;

    /// reserved <ranges/>|<fieldNames/> ;
    qi::rule<It, AST::reserved_t(), skipper_type> reserved;
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<std::string>(), skipper_type> field_names;

    /// <optionName/> = <constant/>
    qi::rule<It, AST::enum_val_opt_t(), skipper_type> enum_val_opt;
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<AST::enum_val_opt_t>(), skipper_type> enum_val_opts;
    /// <ident/> = <int/> [ +<enumValueOption/> ] ;
    qi::rule<It, AST::enum_field_t(), skipper_type> enum_field;
    qi::rule<It, AST::enum_body_t(), skipper_type> enum_body;
    qi::rule<It, AST::enum_t(), skipper_type> enum_;

    // TODO: TBD: continue here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto2-spec#message_definition
    /// message <messageName/> <messageBody/>
    qi::rule<It, AST::msg_t(), skipper_type> msg;
    /// *{ <field/> | <enum/> | <message/> | <extend/> | <extensions/> | <group/>
    ///    | <option/> | <oneof/> | <mapField/> | <reserved/> | <emptyStatement/> }
    qi::rule<It, AST::msg_body_t(), skipper_type> msg_body;

    // TODO: TBD: not sure how appropriate it would be to reach these cases, but we'll see what happens...
    /// extend <messageType/> *{ <field/> | <group/> | <emptyStatement/> }
    qi::rule<It, AST::extend_t::content_t(), skipper_type> extend_content;
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<AST::extend_t::content_t>(), skipper_type> extend_contents;
    qi::rule<It, AST::extend_t(), skipper_type> extend;

    // TODO: TBD: ditto comments in the rule definition section.
    // service; rpc; stream;

    /// topLevelDef = <message/> | <enum/> | <extend/> | <service/>
    qi::rule<It, AST::top_level_def_t(), skipper_type> top_level_def;
    /// <syntax/> { <import/> | <package/> | <option/> | <option/> | <emptyStatement/> }
    qi::rule<It, AST::proto_t(), skipper_type> proto;
    qi::rule<It, AST::proto_t()> start;
};

#include <fstream>
int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("sample.proto");
    std::string const input(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

    ProtoGrammar<It> const g;
    AST::proto_t parsed;
    bool ok = qi::parse(f, l, g, parsed);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parse succeeded\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f != l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Which for a sample input of

```
syntax = "proto2";
import "demo_stuff.proto";

package StackOverflow;

message Sample {
    optional StuffMsg foo_list = 1;
    optional StuffMsg bar_list = 2;
    optional StuffMsg qux_list = 3;
}

message TransportResult {
    message Sentinel {}
    oneof Chunk {
        Sample payload         = 1;
        Sentinel end_of_stream = 2;
    }
}

message ShowTime {
    optional uint32 magic = 1 [ default = 0xBDF69E88 ];
    repeated string parameters = 2;
    optional string version_info = 3;
}
```

Prints

```
<proto>
  <try>syntax = "proto2";\ni</try>
  <syntax>
    <try>syntax = "proto2";\ni</try>
    <success>\nimport "demo_stuff.</success>
    <attributes>[[N3AST8syntax_tE]]</attributes>
  </syntax>
  <import>
    <try>\nimport "demo_stuff.</try>
    <import_modifier>
      <try> "demo_stuff.proto";</try>
      <fail/>
    </import_modifier>
    <str_lit>
      <try>"demo_stuff.proto";\n</try>
    [ ...
           much 
                 snipped
                          ... ]
  <empty_statement>
    <try>\n\n</try>
    <fail/>
  </empty_statement>
  <success>\n\n</success>
  <attributes>[[[N3AST8syntax_tE], [[[empty], [d, e, m, o, _, s, t, u, f, f, ., p, r, o, t, o]], [[S, t, a, c, k, O, v, e, r, f, l, o, w]], [[[S, a, m, p, l, e], [[[], [S, t, u, f, f, M, s, g], [f, o, o, _, l, i, s, t], 1, []], [[], [S, t, u, f, f, M, s, g], [b, a, r, _, l, i, s, t], 2, []], [[], [S, t, u, f, f, M, s, g], [q, u, x, _, l, i, s, t], 3, []]]]], [[[T, r, a, n, s, p, o, r, t, R, e, s, u, l, t], [[[S, e, n, t, i, n, e, l], []], [[C, h, u, n, k], [[[S, a, m, p, l, e], [p, a, y, l, o, a, d], 1, []], [[S, e, n, t, i, n, e, l], [e, n, d, _, o, f, _, s, t, r, e, a, m], 2, []]]]]]], [[[S, h, o, w, T, i, m, e], [[[], [u, i, n, t, 3, 2], [m, a, g, i, c], 1, [[[d, e, f, a, u, l, t], 3187056264]]], [[], [s, t, r, i, n, g], [p, a, r, a, m, e, t, e, r, s], 2, []], [[], [s, t, r, i, n, g], [v, e, r, s, i, o, n, _, i, n, f, o], 3, []]]]]]]]</attributes>
</proto>
Parse succeeded
Remaining unparsed input: '

'
```

---

¹ (Conflating "recursive descent" (a parsing concept) with recursive variants is confusing too).

² Sadly it exceeds the capacity of both Wandbox and Coliru

Comment: Wow. I don't know if this is where I'll end up with the approach I was on... **BUT** , I was really not expecting **HALF** of this. Hat tip to you, friend. I will take some time to digest how you worked around some of the issues, i.e. using aliases. Did *NOT* know you could even do that, for instance.

Comment: ² Sadly... I don't think it's exclusive to Wadbox or Coliru. At least not without help, if the message is accurate. Literally, *fatal error C1128: number of sections exceeded object file format limit: compile with /bigobj*.

Comment: @mwpowellhtx It is exclusive to the online compilers. Perhpas you run into the known limitation with MSVC - but enabling optimizations and disabling some particular warnings usually gets around it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607238/how-to-avoid-boostphoenix-when-generating-with-boostspiritkarma

Comment: Then there's the matter of the comment skipper ... Or worse, deciding whether/how to support comments as a first class element in the AST. ;-) However, that's beyond the scope of this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just summarize [a couple of key points](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/573d942b1a524b5d) I observed digesting. First, wow, some of it I do not think is documented, in Spirit Qi pages, etc, unless you happened to have heard about it through little birds, etc. That to say, thanks so much for the insights!

Interesting, transformed things directly to language level whenever possible. For instance, `bool_t`, deriving directly from `std::string`, and even `syntax_t`, to name a few. Did not think one could even do that from a parser/AST perspective, but it makes sense.

Very interesting, deriving from `std::string`. As above, did not know that.

```
struct element_type_t : std::string {
    using std::string::string;
    using std::string::operator=;
};
```

In particular, with emphasis on `string` and `operator=`, I'm assuming to help the parser rules, attribute propagation, etc.

Yes, I wondered about support for `std::optional` and `std::variant`, but it would make sense considering [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) maturity. Good points re: leveraging `boost` constructs of the same in lieu of `std`.

Did not know you could define aliases. It would make sense instead of defining a first class struct. For instance,

```
using const_t = variant<full_id_t, int_t, float_t, str_t, bool_t>;
```

Interesting `label_t` aliasing. Although I may pursue that being a language level enum with corresponding rule attribution. Still, `up-vote` for so much effort here.

```
using label_t = std::string;
```

Then the forward declaration and alias of the problem area, `msg_body_t`. ***INTERESTING*** I had no idea. Really.

```
struct field_t;
struct enum_t;
struct msg_t;
struct extend_t;
struct extensions_t;
struct group_t;
struct option_t;
struct oneof_t;
struct map_field_t;
struct reserved_t;

using msg_body_t = std::vector<variant<
    field_t,
    enum_t,
    msg_t,
    extend_t,
    extensions_t,
    group_t,
    option_t,
    oneof_t,
    map_field_t,
    reserved_t,
    empty_statement_t
>>;
```

Still, I'm not sure how that avoids the C++ *C2079* (VS2017) forward declaration issue? I'll have to double check in my project code, but it ran for you, obviously, so something about that must be more kosher than I am thinking.

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::option_t, name, val)
// etc ...
```

And which simplifies the struct adaptation significantly, I imagine.

Eventually, yes, I would want a skipper involved. I had not quite gotten that far yet when I stumbled on the forward declaration issue.

```
using skipper_type = qi::space_type;
// ...
start = qi::skip(qi::space) [ proto ];
// ...
qi::rule<It, AST::msg_type_t(), skipper_type> msg_type;
```

For many of the rule definitions, `=` or `%=`? The prevailing wisdom I've heard over the years is to prefer `%=`. Your thoughts? i.e.

```
id = lexeme[qi::alpha >> *char_("A-Za-z0-9_")];
// ^, or:
id %= lexeme[qi::alpha >> *char_("A-Za-z0-9_")];
// ^^ ?
```

Makes sense for these to land in an language friendly AST attribution:

```
oct_lit = &char_('0')       >> qi::uint_parser<AST::int_t, 8>{};
hex_lit = qi::no_case["0x"] >> qi::uint_parser<AST::int_t, 16>{};
dec_lit =                      qi::uint_parser<AST::int_t, 10>{};
int_lit = lexeme[hex_lit | oct_lit | dec_lit]; // ordering is important
// Yes, I understand why, because 0x... | 0... | dig -> that to say, great point!
```

I did not spend as much time as I should, perhaps, exploring the bits exposed by Qi here, i.e. `qi::upper`, etc, but it's a great point:

```
group_name = &qi::upper >> id;
```

Did not know this operator was a thing for `char_`. I do not think it is documented, however, unless you happened to have heard it from little birdies:

```
//         Again, great points re: numerical/parser ordering.
char_val = hex_esc | oct_esc | char_esc | ~char_("\0\n\\");
//                                        ^
```

Not sure what you mean here, *"likely redundant"*. However, it is ***VERY*** interesting that you can produce the attribution here. I like that a lot.

```
// Empty Statement - likely redundant
empty_statement = ';' >> qi::attr(AST::empty_statement_t{});
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you mean in terms of whether the semi-colon is redundant, I thought so as well, at first. Then I studied the rest of the grammar, and rather than second guess things, no, I agree with the grammar: *"empty statement"* really is an empty statement, at least when you accept it in the context of the grammatical alternatives. Sometimes, however, the semi-colon does indicate what you and I thought it was: that is, *"end of statement"* or `eos`, which caused me to raise an eyebrow at first as well.

I also did not know you could attribute things directly during a Qi rule. In fact, the general guidance I'd been considering was to avoid semantic actions. But I suppose these are different animals than `qi::attr(...)` per se.

Nice approach here. Plus it lends consistency to the rule definitions. Cannot `up-vote` enough for this one, among others.

```
#define KW(p) (lexeme[(p) >> !(qi::alnum | '_')])
```

Here I am considering language level enumerated values, but it is interesting nontheless.

```
label = KW("required")
    | KW("optional")
    | KW("repeated")
    ;
```

Here, the long and the short of it is, fewer rules involved. It is a bit messier in terms of all the strings, etc, but I like that it more or less reads one-for-one with the grammar to inform the definition.

```
    // mapField = "map" "<" keyType "," type ">" mapName "=" fieldNumber [ "[" fieldOptions "]" ] ";"
    map_field = KW("map") >> '<' >> key_type >> ',' >> type >> '>' >> map_name
        >> '=' >> field_num >> field_opts >> ';';
```

I wondered about whether Qi symbols might be useful, but I had no idea these bits would be that useful:

```
struct escapes_t : qi::symbols<char, char> {
    escapes_t() { this->add
            ("\\a",  '\a')
            ("\\b",  '\b')
            ("\\f",  '\f')
            ("\\n",  '\n')
            ("\\r",  '\r')
            ("\\t",  '\t')
            ("\\v",  '\v')
            ("\\\\", '\\')
            ("\\'",  '\'')
            ("\\\"", '"');
    }
} char_esc;
```

Ditto symbols, `up-vote`:

```
struct builtin_type_t : qi::symbols<char, std::string> { /* ... */ };
```

In summary, very impressed here. Thank you so much for the insights.

Comment: Nice work. I'm still prepared to add explanations. Thing is, the extra info will not fit into my existing answer due to size limits. Since your own reponse (which is technically not answer) poses many new questions, perhaps what you can do is to post this as a new question (linking to this page) and I'll post my explanations there, making sure to address all the points you asked to confirm here.

Comment: Can you add "another" answer? That's what I would suggest, if possible, working within the constraints offered by the forum. Thanks so much.

Comment: I won't, because this is not  a forum, but a Q&A site. Actually, the guidelines encourage more pointed questions, instead of prolonged discussion. The point of it is that if the post combines many questions or a specific complex of applications, the answer will be of limited use to others. In this case I feel it will be really useless to have many answers that really form an anachronistic discussion. One can do that on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/. But to be honest I'll probably just leave it. I think you got the gist and I think you'll figure out the little confusions on your own.

Answer (score 0):

There was a slight oversight in the ranges I think. Referring to the [proto2 Extensions specification](http://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto2-spec#extensions), literally we have:

```
range =  intLit [ "to" ( intLit | "max" ) ]
```

Then adjusting in the AST:

```
enum range_max_t { max };

struct range_t {
    int_t min;
    boost::optional<boost::variant<int_t, range_max_t>> max;
};
```

And last but not least in the grammar:

```
range %= int_lit >> -(KW("to") >> (int_lit | KW_ATTR("max", ast::range_max_t::max)));
```

With the helper:

```
#define KW_ATTR(p, a) (qi::lexeme[(p) >> !(qi::alnum | '_')] >> qi::attr(a))
```

Untested, but my confidence is higher today than it was yesterday that this approach is on the right track.

Worst case, if there are any type conflicts between the `int_t`, which is basically defined as `long long` and the enumerated type `range_max_t`, then I could just store the keyword `"max"` for the same effect.

That's a worst case; I'd like to keep it as simple as possible but not lose sight of the specification at the same time.

Anyway, thanks again for the insights! `up-vote`

Comment: Well, I ran with it a little further. There were a couple of problems, probably inconsistencies between AST and grammar. I am working that out. The one I just resolved:

    ``struct enum_field_t : has_name, 
    has_opts<boost::optional<std::vector<enum_val_option_t>>> {
        int_t ordinal;
    };``.

Which, as you can probably tell, did a bit of refactoring for repetitious AST aspects, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I completely understand this aspect, apart from one builds and the other does not.

With `extend_t` you introduce a `using` type alias `content_t`. I "get it", in the sense that this magically "just works". For instance:

```
struct extend_t {
    using content_t = boost::variant<field_t, group_t, empty_statement_t>;
    msg_type_t msg_type;
    std::vector<content_t> content;
};
```

However, contrasting that with a more traditional template inheritance and type definition, I'm not sure why that does not work. For instance:

```
template<typename Content>
struct has_content {
    typedef Content content_type;
    content_type content;
};

// It is noteworthy, would need to identify the std::vector::value_type as well...
struct extend_t : has_content<std::vector<boost::variant<field_t, group_t, empty_statement_t>>> {
    msg_type_t msg_type;
};
```

In which case, I start seeing symptoms of the *forward declaration* in the form of *incomplete type* errors.

I am hesitant to accept the one as *"gospel"* as it were without having a better understanding as to why it is.